# Is the Google Id/Subject string returned from a GoogleIDToken validation actually a number?

Tags: google-signin

I'm currently looking into server-side validation of a GoogleIDToken for Google Sign-in (Android & iOS). [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server)

In the example, the "sub" field in the object returned by the Google API endpoint is read as a string, but it looks like it may actually be a (really big) number.

Some other tests using some users on my side also show big numbers.

Looking deeper in the Payload documentation, it looks like this value could be null, but outside of this possibility, can we assume that this string is actually a number?

This is important because we want to store it in a database, and saving it as a number might actually be more efficient than a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on the team at Google: this value should be stored as a string, it may be parseable as a number, but there is no guarantee, do not rely on that assumption!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do arithmetic on it, then store it as a number. Otherwise, don't.

This is a general rule.